# How to check primary is not parentID in the same table

Tags: sql-server, parent-child, sql-delete

How to delete rows from table that contain parent-child relation. I search on records that did not change status the last 12 hours and that have not children, meaning I have to find out if it is a parent for other record. 
My query look like the following:

```
SELECT ItemID, ParentID, StatusID FROM table1
WHERE Digitalstatus = 1 AND LastChangedDateTime>= DATEADD(HOUR,-12, GETDATE()) AND StatusID = 1 


MemberID    ItemID      ParentID    StatusID
--------       --------      ------     --------
500006      4663119     NULL            1
687194      4663121     NULL            1
```

and when I search on one of the members, I can see that the ItemID is a parent in other records

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE MemberID = 500006

MemberID    ItemID      ParentID    StatusID
--------    -------     --------    --------
 500006     3667431     NULL            1
 500006     3704851     3667431         2
 500006     4663041     NULL            1
 500006     4663119     NULL            1
 500006     4663120     4663119         2
 500006     3792268     3704851         3
 500006     4663124     4663120         3
```

My question is how to find only the ItemID where it is not a parent for other records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an exists clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE
    MemberID = 500006 AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 a
                WHERE a.MemberID = 500006 AND a.ParentID = t1.ItemID);
```

The logic of the above query reads fairly close to your requirement, and only retains a record if its `ItemID` does not also serve as some other record's `ParentID`.